# Spool Output getting splitted

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

My spool output is getting splitted into two lines along with blank space at each line.

i am using this setting.

```
  set colsep ,
  set pagesize 0
  set trimspool on
  set trim on
  set headsep off
  set feedback off
  set echo off
  set timing off
  set termout off
  set linesize 4000
  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED FORMAT WORD_WRAPPED
  SET LONG 2000000000
  SET SQLFORMAT ANSICONSOLE
```

output

```
2010123100001001574964||||||5000053895489|||||BUILD|19-AUG-16||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||23-MAR-15|||||||30-DEC-14|||||SJONDUS||DJKSKIKIYN||

2012123100001000780125||||||5000018234592|||||BUILD|19-AUG-16||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||23-MAR-15|||||||23-NOV-14|||||SAMPLEFILE||samplethief||
```

so two lines becomes 6 including blank line. 
what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your query

Comment: I see you have tagged [PL/SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsqldeveloper/info) and not [SQL\*Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlplus/info). PL/SQL Developer 12 doesn't support `headsep`, `trimspool` or `sqlformat`. Or if this is actually SQL\*Plus, what version do you have?

Comment: Now that I check, `set sqlformat` isn't in SQL\*Plus or PL/SQL Developer, it's from SQL Developer and SQLcl.